# Passing variable in cat command to grep the specific passed variable values

Tags: bash, shell-script, logs

I am trying to grep specific timestamp + required string inside logs, please see below code

```
month=`echo $(date) | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
zero=0
year=`echo $(date) | cut -d ' ' -f 6`

date1=$zero$(echo $(date) | cut -d ' ' -f 3)

currenttiemstamp=`echo $(date) | cut -d ' ' -f 4`


currenthr=`echo $(date) | cut -d ' ' -f 4 |cut -d ':' -f 1`
currentmin=`echo $(date) | cut -d ' ' -f 4 |cut -d ' ' -f 2`
currentmin1=`expr $(echo $(date) | cut -d ' ' -f 4 |cut -d ':' -f 2) - 6`

x="Error Message"

**Assigning timestamp string to a variable
stringtocheck=$date1" "$month" "$year" "$currenthr":"$currentmin1**

#printing timestamp string
echo "$stringtocheck"

cd /log/
**cat xyz.log |grep "^ "$stringtocheck""|grep "^ "$x""**
```

even in above cat command I tried with single quote it is not showing the result anyway

Please let me now if I am doing right thing here , I am completely new in shell scripting world.

Comment: can you show what output you needed , just edit your question and had your output what output you needed , otherwise it is really difficult to come up with solution

Comment: The `date` command can show you everything you're asking for without piping through cut. I tried your first variable and got today's date, not month.

Comment: [About `echo $(date)`](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690).

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point out many of the problems with your script; you should fix what it points out first. Then... you run `date` a lot to get different fields; why not just run it once with a format string to get the fields you want (I think you want `date +"%d %a %Y %H"` to get everything except `currentmin1`)? And `currentmin1` is weird; if the current minute is less than 6, it'll be negative; if between 6 and 15, it'll be a single digit. Is this intentional? If not, what *is* the intent?

Comment: Also `grep '^thing' | grep '^somethingelse'` will never print anything.

Comment: Thanks everyone for puting your thoughts here..@rowboat actually when I am greping same thing inside /logs directory I am getting the required string greped in result..                 
 @Gordon Davisson thanks for the response ,  yes that is intentionally I put there, I will be rewriting it post I am reaching to the expected result which i am not yet,  although  my requirement is currentmin1= currentmin -1 only.. so you can avoid that.. here also I am going  to handle this (less than 1 )with conditional, also I will prefix 0-9 with zero..

Comment: @rohitshinde Is the actual goal to get the time as of 1 minute ago? If so, rather than writing a messy conditional yourself, just ask the `date` command to do the adjustment. Unfortunately, the syntax for this is not portable; if you're using GNU `date`, it'd be something like `date --date="now - 1 minute" +"%d %a %Y %H:%M"`; but with bsd `date`, it'd be `date -v -1M +"%d %a %Y %H:%M"`.

Comment: @codeholic24  Hi, here is the requirement:
check and see if in last 1 to 2 mins the log has a message below:
"06 Dec 2020 22:51:50,6000000  - next person is not available" ,if  log has this message then there is no issue, this can be handled with if else and in else we can echo ""if has issue and not seeing the message for in last 1-2 mins.

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks much, here is the what I got in required timestamp timestamptocheck=$(date --date="now - 1 minute" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M"),I am proceeding further ...thanks!

Comment: FYI thanks for the help guys.
I am just closing my question with an answer grep "$(date --date="now - 1 minute" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M")" xyz.log | grep "Error message", similarly I can check for last 5 mins by using loop

Answer (score 0):

I am just closing my question with an answer

```
grep "$(date --date="now - 1 minute" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M")" xyz.log | grep "Error message"
```

Similarly I can check for last 5 minutes by using loop.